# Programming auto-correlation function calculation

Tags: correlation-functions, fortran

I have a set of data (heat flow) values in x, y and z directions for which I have to calculate the auto-correlation function to get the thermal conductivity. I have written a small Fortran90 code but something is wrong because I get irrelevant results. I am not sure whether this a problem of units or a problem of coding the algorithm.

The data look like this (I am adding comments):

```
10000      ! number of data
3.0000     ! time step (dt)
1281.4610  ! cell volume (V)
2000.0     ! temperature (T)
64         ! number of atoms
9.746633E-03 -1.185578E-02 -2.107013E-02
3.909507E-02 -5.904692E-05 -3.044154E-03
7.439500E-02 2.270370E-02 3.536638E-03
1.027890E-01 3.875051E-02 1.377188E-02
1.218158E-01 4.606921E-02 2.570092E-02
1.306354E-01 4.482340E-02 3.692641E-02
...    !   10000 such lines
```

The function to calculate is:

$$
\frac{1}{3Vk_BT^{3/2}}\int_0^{+\infty}{\langle q(0)q(t)\rangle dt}
$$

The Fortran code I wrote is the following:

```
program kappa

    implicit none
    
    integer, parameter :: dp=selected_real_kind(15,307)
    
    real(dp), parameter :: kB=1.380649d-23
    real(dp), parameter :: eV2J = 1.602d-19
    real(dp), parameter :: ang2m = 1.0d-10
    real(dp), parameter :: fs2s = 1.0d-15
    
    real(dp), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: q ! heat flow
    real(dp), dimension(3) :: q_0, q_t, int_q ! reference heat flow, integrated heat flow at t, and integrated heat flow
    real(dp) :: dt ! time step
    real(dp) :: V, T ! Volume and temperature
    integer :: count_q ! number of steps (corresponds to number of line of HEAT)
    integer :: natoms
    integer :: ios, i, j
    
    
    int_q(:) = 0.0_dp
    
    
    read( 10, * ) count_q
    allocate(q(count_q,3))
    
    read( 10, * ) dt
    read( 10, * ) V
    read( 10, * ) T
    read( 10, * ) natoms
    
    open(20, file='thermal_cond.dat', status='unknown', action='write')
    
    
    ! store all the heat flow values in q(:,:)
    lp1: do i = 1, count_q
        read( 10, *, iostat=ios ) q(i,:) 
        if (ios < 0) exit lp1 ! unexpected end of file: this should not happen
    end do lp1
    
    ! for each q_0(:) up to t/2 (t=total time of the simulation) 
    ! calculate the autocorrelation function <q(0)q(t)>
    do i = 1, int(count_q / 2)
        q_0(:) = q(i,:) ! shift the reference heat flow by one step
        q_t(:) = 0.0_dp ! initialize the value of <q(0)q(t)>
        
        do j = i + 1, int(count_q / 2) + (i - 1) ! shift the right end of the interval to have it constant (length of count_q/2)
            q_t(:) = q_t(:) + q(j,:) * q_0(:)
        end do

        q_t(:) = q_t(:) * eV2J**2 / ( int(count_q / 2) * natoms * 3.0 * V * ang2m**3 * kB * T**2 ) * dt * fs2s
        int_q(:) = int_q(:) + q_t(:) 

        write(20, '(4F15.9)') (i - 1) * dt, q_t(:)

    end do
    
    
    
    
    write(6,*) 'Kappa(x) = ', int_q(1)
    write(6,*) 'Kappa(y) = ', int_q(2)
    write(6,*) 'Kappa(z) = ', int_q(3)
    write(6,*) '< Kappa > = ', sqrt(int_q(1)**2 + int_q(2)**2 + int_q(3)**2)
    
    close(20)


end program kappa_ml
```

Could anyone tell me if something is wrong in the program?
Thank you

Comment: Can you include the autocorrelation function you are getting and a comparison with a rough image of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: Somehow providing the input data would really help - we can then compile and run it. Can you provide a small case which illustrates the problem?

Comment: Well I don't know if it is your problem but you could help yourself by working in more natural units for the problem - there are a number of quantities like  eV2J\*\*2 and ang2m**3 * kB which will be tiny and may make the floating point you are using struggle to represent the huge range of numbers you are trying to use.

Comment: I try to enclose the full data file. To answer Ian, the energy is given in eV so I assumed I should multiply by eV2J**2, but that's still a problem I have not fully soved. As to ang2m**3, this is to transform the volume from anstrom to meter. I am sure for the volume.

Comment: Here is a link where the files can be retrieved:
[Renater](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=6a624d27-dd77-49d8-b65a-fc91e8bcb51c)

Comment: Ian, to be more clear: the property to calculate is the thermal conductivity, so in W/(m.K). If the energy is in eV and the volume in angstrom, I won't get the right units of kappa.

Comment: Tyberius: this is a run test for liquid silicon, hence the high temperature of 2000K. Kappa for silicon is around 150 W/(m.K), but I am not sure it is for liquid Si. If not (i.e. for solid), kappa should then be smaller than 150, but still very appreciable (10 or above).

Comment: @Pascal Are you interested in computing the autocorrelation function (ACF) or the integrated autocorrelation time (IAC) as the answer below alludes? These are two separate concepts with differing complexities.

Comment: @Scientist: thank you for your comment. Actually, I would like both the  Heat-flux ACF (HFACF) and its integration as it corresponds to thermal conductivity. I want to be able to plot a graph similar to Fig.5 published in the following paper:  [arxiv] (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.15002.pdf). As I understand from this paper, my program is not integrating correctly the data.

Comment: @Pascal The most efficient ACF computation method as others said is FFT, for which there are a number of high-quality Fortran packages. But if you need a simple homemade solution that gets the work done, check out the `CrossCorr_mod` module of the [ParaMonte library](https://github.com/cdslaborg/paramonte/blob/main/src/kernel/CrossCorr_mod.f90). Of interest are `getCrossCorrFFT()` which computes ACF via FFT, and `getBatchMeansIAC()` which computes the integrated autocorrelation time (IAC) of an ACF using the batch-means method, which is among the most reliable methods of estimating IAC.

Comment: @Scientist: thank you for your help. I am going to dig into these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the Fortran code, but in general, calculating the integrated autocorrelation correctly is a subtle exercise. There is increasing uncertainty in estimating correlation at increasing time lags, as you will see if you plot your integrand as a function of *t*, which means that the more of your autocorrelation series you try to integrate over the noisier your final estimate will be.

One thing you need to do is to *censor* your integral -- instead of taking it to infinite time, stop it at some T which is a suitable multiple of the correlation time. A typical value is between 5 to 10 correlation times. For more details on why this works, and an implementation in Python, see: [Autocorrelation time estimation](https://dfm.io/posts/autocorr/). (The autocorrelation integral you need is simply the autocorrelation time multiplied by the variance.)